# give an exact number

Tags: word-choice

I heard on the following web site that one person says "* give an exact number.."
http://loe.org/shows/shows.html?programID=12-P13-00043

I wonder whether or not the "give" can be used as a verb in a formal presentation?

Is the word formal? If not, what are the formal verbs used in presentation?

Comment: The word "give" can be used in formal and informal contexts. It's fine to use it in a presentation. Don't try to avoid it; that's likely to make your speech sound unnatural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Give" is perfectly fine to use in most situations, though "provide" may sound more professional and fit the context of the phrase better.

For example:

> "...provide an exact number to the program."

May sound more appropriate than:

> "...give an exact number to the program."

This all depends on the context in which the phrase is used, of course.